# delete column from table when deleted package in laravel

Tags: eloquent, composer-php, laravel-5.7

When a field in the database is added by installing a package, how do I make sure that it is removed when I uninstall the package. Will it be deleted?

Comment: Thank you for the question, omid. Please include specific information if you are able to. Can you provide the name of the package that you are uninstalling? This will allow us to look at the code to be sure we are providing a correct answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How is this related to Composer itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many Laravel packages come with migrations that create tables (and fields at times) like this:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create($this->getTableName(), function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

and usually, remove them on tear down

```
/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists($this->getTableName());
}
```

However, sometimes things go wrong and you may want to check yourself. Refer the `database/migrations` file that shipped with the package and see what was created and compare it to the tables/columns you see in your database.